# can't delete folders on samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, rm, autofs

I am dealing with a really weird issue I can't identify the cause of. I have a samba share mounted using autofs in Rocky 9.2 with the flags `-fstype=cifs,rw,nounix,file_mode=0700,dir_mode=0700,multiuser,sec=krb5,user=username,cruid=username,gid=primarygroup,_netdev`.

It mounts fine and I can add and delete files fine but folders are behaving very weirdly when I try to delete things. For example the following:

```bash
$ mkdir dir
$ mkdir dir/{a,b}
$ touch dir/{a,b}/f{1..5}
$ tree dir
dir
├── a
│   ├── f1
│   ├── f2
│   ├── f3
│   ├── f4
│   └── f5
└── b
    ├── f1
    ├── f2
    ├── f3
    ├── f4
    └── f5

2 directories, 10 files
$ rm --recursive --force --verbose dir
removed 'dir/b/f2'
removed 'dir/b/f4'
removed 'dir/b/f5'
removed 'dir/b/f1'
removed 'dir/b/f3'
removed directory 'dir/b'
removed 'dir/a/f2'
removed 'dir/a/f4'
removed 'dir/a/f5'
removed 'dir/a/f1'
removed 'dir/a/f3'
removed directory 'dir/a'
rm: cannot remove 'dir': Directory not empty
$ tree dir
dir
├── a
└── b

2 directories, 0 files
$ rm --recursive --force --verbose dir
rm: cannot remove 'dir': Directory not empty
$ ls --all --recursive dir # in the output note the lack of . and .. in dir/a and dir/b
dir:
.  ..  a  b

dir/a:

dir/b:
$ rmdir dir/a
rmdir: failed to remove 'dir/a': No such file or directory
$ rmdir dir/b
rmdir: failed to remove 'dir/b': No such file or directory
$ tree dir
dir
├── a
└── b

2 directories, 0 files
$ ls --all --recursive -l dir
dir:
total 0
drwx------. 2 username primarygroup 0 Jun  9 16:23 .
drwx------. 2 username primarygroup 0 Jun  9 16:23 ..
drwx------. 2 username primarygroup 0 Jun  9 16:23 a
drwx------. 2 username primarygroup 0 Jun  9 16:23 b

dir/a:
total 0

dir/b:
total 0
```

I've tried doing it as root, making the permissions `0777` for both files and directories, and mounting it manually rather than with autofs and I get the same behaviour.

No relevant messages seem to be turning up in the logs (not discounting I may not be looking at the right log).

Update 1: Switching off SELinux didn't help. Nor did turning off the firewall.

Update 2: It seems like restarting autofs will clear them (usually requires a restart). But it won't consistently remove all of them. After 2 restarts and with no extra calls to `rm` or `rmdir` the folders had completely disappeared. But I can still recreate the problem. So I guess the SMB server must have the correct information but it's not being represented locally maybe...?

Update 3: I turned on logging for `cifs`. I did this with `echo 7 | sudo tee /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI`. Then when I go through a simpler version of the steps again:

```bash
$ mkdir --parent h/a
```

at the same time in logs we get:

```
Jun 12 16:04:56 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

```bash
$ rm --recursive h
```

```
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0x80000006 STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0x80000006 STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:12 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000101 STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY
```

```bash
$ rm --recursive h
```

```
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0x80000006 STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
Jun 12 16:05:27 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
```

```bash
$ tree h
h
└── a

1 directory, 0 files
```

```
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0x80000006 STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
Jun 12 16:07:28 localhost kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
```

Comment: so it lies when it says `removed directory 'dir/b'` and `removed directory 'dir/a'` - that's odd

Comment: not an expert here, but I am willing to bet that selinux is involved here, notice the dot at the end of the permissions.

Comment: I liked your thinking @RowlandPenny but I just disabled SELinux and rebooted and it still seems to be happening.

Comment: The "STATUS_DELETE_PENDING" suggests some other client may have been accessing the directories, and held a CIFS oplock for them. The delete operation causes such oplocks to be broken, so [according to the spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cifs/fbac1bf1-8df6-4cde-86b7-d345c9833a2d) the delete operation must hold until either the client in question acknowledges the oplock break message sent by the server, or the oplock break ack timer expires (as the client may be unreachable because abruptly disconnected or crashed).

Comment: In this case I'm fairly confident the client I'm running is the only one accessing the directories.